# Can you extract a program from the EV3 brick to the computer?

Tags: ev3, programming

As part of an assignment, I made a program for my EV3, but however my computer automatically restarted, so I lost that program. I need to show the program!  However, the program is still in my brick. So, I was wondering, is there any way to extract a program from a brick to my computer? And if there is, what would I need? (extra software, Bluetooth, connection cable)? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**Update:**

There is a tool at http://ev3treevis.azurewebsites.net/ that can be use to create a new `.ev3` file from a `.rbf` file recovered from an EV3 brick. Some information will be lost, but at least simple programs should be able to be recovered.

**Original answer:**

You can extract the compiled program from the EV3. Compiled programs have a `.rbf` file extension. However, these files only contain EV3 VM bytecodes and cannot be converted back to the EV3-G project file format (`.ev3p` file extension).

Details about extracting the program from the brick and what you can do with it has already been answered [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/4252/3498).