# Is there any way to unzip an ev3 file into text and xml files?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

I would like to access the text file of the project files (.ev3p) to know their structure. But in the Mindstorms software, I couldn't find any way to download the .ev3p files.

Comment: Hi theboguz and welcome to Bricks.SE! It seems there is a significant disconnect between the question title and body - do you wish to download an .ev3p file or unzip an .ev3 file?

Comment: Sorry, @zovits! I would like to unzip an .ev3 file into other files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Lab Code](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4251/export-lego-mindstorms-ev3-lab-code)

Comment: As several previous answers on this  stack exchange site have already clarified, an ev3 file is a .zip file. Rename it and change the extension to .zip and you'll be able to open it. What's inside it is documented here: https://afarago.github.io/EV3TreeVisualizerPages/filesyntax.html